# how to get geolocation data(latitude, longitude) correctly from firebase (flutter/dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

[image]

this is my firebase
on this request I get this kind of data

```
final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;
firestoreInstance.collection("locations").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
        print(result.data);
      });
    });
```

Here comes a response from the server

```
{12/5/2020: {geohash: u8vybwryv, geopoint: Instance of 'GeoPoint'}} .... and all list of documents
```

after i use this

```
 firestoreInstance.collection("test").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
        print(result.data['geopoint'].latitude.toString());
      });
   });
```

and receive in debug null.

how to get latitude and longitude and not null?

Comment: there is an article in medium called "Working with Geolocation and Geocoding in Flutter (And Integration with Maps)"
which I think could help you to resolve your question: https://medium.com/swlh/working-with-geolocation-and-geocoding-in-flutter-and-integration-with-maps-16fb0bc35ede

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe helpful for someone

```
List<LatLng> polyLinesLatLongs = List<LatLng>(); // our list of geopoints

_someFunction() {
    firestoreInstance
        .collection("userId") // your collection
        .document('history') //your document
        .collection("locations") //your collection
        .getDocuments()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      var fireBase = querySnapshot.documents;
      for (var i = 1; i < fireBase.length; i++) {

        GeoPoint point = fireBase[i].data['position']['geopoint']; //that way to take instance of geopoint

        polyLinesLatLongs.add(LatLng(double.parse('${point.latitude}'),
              double.parse('${point.longitude}'))); // now we can add our point to list
    });
  }
```